# highlight image section through image mapster

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need a help.

I have a page(xyz.html) where i have few sponsors logos(1,2,3,4,5 etc). I want to click on each logo and that click will take me to another page(abc.html) where I will have a floor plan image.

I want if a user is clicking on sponsors logo 1 from xyz.html. it should take the user to abc.html page and highlight the 1 maped image there.

I have tried it, need help if anyone can help me to make it in more easier way.

```
<script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/clientevents/Image-mapping/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
  $(function() {
   $(function() {
        $(document).on('click','area',function(){
            var targetId = j$(this).data('target-id');
            sessionStorage.setItem('highlightId',targetId);
            window.location.href = "{[E-CUSTOM URL:Floor Plan]}";
        });
  });
  });
  </script>
```

Below code will come in abc.html page.

```
<script>
  $(function() {
        var id = sessionStorage.getItem('highlightId');
      sessionStorage.removeItem('highlightId');
     //  $('#' + id).css('background-color','yellow');

       $('img').mapster( {fillColor: 'ff0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.5});
     $('#' + id).mapster('select');          
  });
  </script>
<script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/clientevents/Image-mapping/jquery.imagemapster.js"></script>
```